# SQL: cleaning a DB, checking that there's no violation and maybe rolling back

Tags: sql, oracle, error-handling, rollback

I'd like to clean some DEV DBs.  I've got script doing lots of "delete from" that I didn't write.  I'm not sure they'll leave the DB in a correct state (it's a dev DB so it's not that bad, but still...).

I was wondering, can I wrap the SQL cleaning script I got into a transaction and rollback to the prev DB state if, after the deletes, the DB is in violation?

Basically I've got:

```
delete from aaa
delete from bbb
...
delete from zzz
```

and I'd like to do:

```
delete from aaa
delete from bbb
...
delete from zzz
check for violation <-- how do I do this ?
```

and wrap this in a transaction or something that can be rolled back.

How would I go about this? (it's Oracle 10 but standard SQL would be nice).

Comment: What's "violation" mean? Is that an Oracle term?

Comment: While there is a Standard (SQL/PSM) for such code, it is not widely implemented by vendors (postgre only?) For oracle, guessing something like: `DECLARE x NUMBER; SELECT COUNT(*) INTO x FROM YourTable WHERE your_colum = 'illegal value'; IF(x > 0) THEN ROLLBACK END IF;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with oracle when executing some statements use this to ensure that there is no auto commit (normally it is OFF by default)

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT OFF
```

then you can  do a `COMMIT` when you're sure that every thing is ok or `ROLLBACK` if not

Comment: @Iweller: OK great...   And what about checking the DB is in valid state after the delete, can this be done easily before committing when *autocommit* is set to off?

Comment: what you you mean with *checking the DB is in valid state after the delete*? foreign key constraints are checked for each delete statement by DB,